# Using GMP in Eigen3

Tags: eigen, gmp

I am working on some sample program and trying to use matrix functionalities offered by Eigen3 library.
I want to store high precision integer variable(mpz_t) in a (100,100) matrix. For storing integer, there is already inbuilt data type MatrixXd. Similarly, just wanted it for high precision variables. Please share some advices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, all you need to do is declare a `Matrix<mpz_class,Dynamic,Dynamic>` matrix. The `mpz_class` type is a c++ wrapper around `mpz_t` such that it behaves like any scalar type.

Here is an example:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace Eigen;
typedef Matrix<mpz_class,Dynamic,Dynamic> MatrixXz;

int main() {
  MatrixXz A(10,10), B(10,10), C(10,10);
  A.fill(111);
  B.fill(222);
  C = 2*A + B;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am implementing multi precision offered by Boost library.